# Ruby to_a method stuck

Tags: ruby

Please excuse my question, but I'm beginner learning Ruby.
 I have a block of code and don't know how to make the output code to an array. I tried use Ruby `to_a` method but doesn't work, I'm sure this is really simple, but please help me!!!

```
length = 2300                               #line 1
divide = 6                                  #line 2
result = length/divide                      #line 3

1.upto(divide) do |i|                       #line 4
   p foo = i * result                       #line 5
end                                         #line 6
```

Output is `383,766,1149,1532,1915,2298` but my desire is to have `[383,766,1149,1532,1915,2298]`

Answer (score 2):

You need to *push* (with `<<`) your result into an array `foo` for example, something like:

```
length = 2300                               #line 1
divide = 6                                  #line 2
result = length/divide                      #line 3

foo = []
1.upto(divide) do |i|                       #line 4
   foo << i * result                        #line 5
end

p foo #=> [383, 766, 1149, 1532, 1915, 2298]
```

Another way to do this:

```
(1..divide).each_with_object([]) { |r,arr| arr << r*result }
```

See [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)

But you should really be using `map` here:

```
part = length/divide 
p (1..divide).map { |idx| idx*part } #=> [383, 766, 1149, 1532, 1915, 2298]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Range#step](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-step) to get what you want directly :

```
length = 2300
divide = 6
result = length/divide

(result..length).step(result).to_a
#=> [383, 766, 1149, 1532, 1915, 2298]
```

or

```
length = 2300
divide = 6

(0..length).step(length/divide).drop(1)
#=> [383, 766, 1149, 1532, 1915, 2298]
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning an array with the results of running a block once for every element - [that is what `map` does](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

```
length = 2300                               #line 1
divide = 6                                  #line 2
result = length/divide                      #line 3

res = 1.upto(divide).map do |i|             #line 4
   i * result                               #line 5
end 

p res    # => [383, 766, 1149, 1532, 1915, 2298]
```